# LINQ to XML generates \r\n between tags?

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, whitespace

I am generating a XElement having this structure:

```
<TestNames>\r\n <Test>YA</Test>\r\n <Test>YO</Test>\r\n </TestNames>
```

How do I get rid of the whitespaces and \r\n in a non-hack way :)

**Update**:

```
XElement testsXmlDocument= new XElement("TestNames");           

foreach (string test in selectedTests)         
    testsXmlDocument.Add(new XElement("Test",test)); 

return testsXmlDocument.ToString();
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Generating XML? There are several way to do that, so please show a little bit of code that generates this.

Comment: I have updated my sample above!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XElement provides an overload of [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551415.aspx) that takes an argument of type `SaveOptions`. One of the values of this enumeration is `DisableFormatting`.

If this doesn't give you enough control then you need to use the `Save` overload of XElement that takes an instance of [XmlWriter](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=XmlWriter). The output of an XmlWriter can be controlled by using [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx).

Note that the recommended way of creating an XmlWriter is to use the static [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create.aspx) method instead of constructing one directly. If you wantthe output in a string, you can use the overload that takes a [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had to write database data to an xml file and read it back from the xml file, using LINQ to XML. Some fields in a record were themselves xml strings complete with \r characters. These had to remain intact. I spent days trying to find something that would work, but it seems Microsoft was by design converting \r to \n.

The following solution works for me:

To write a loaded XDocument to the XML file keeping \r intact, where xDoc is an XDocument and filePath is a string:

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings 
    { NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None, Indent = true };
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, xmlWriterSettings))
{
    xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
    xmlWriter.Flush();
}
```

To read an XML file into an XElement keeping \r intact:

```
using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(filePath) 
   { WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant })
{
     xmlTextReader.MoveToContent();
     xDatabaseElement = XElement.Load(xmlTextReader);
}
```