# c# convert '\n\r' to '&#x13&#x10;' while saving XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have searched for solution for this but all I found are questions how to prevent this.

I have a simple code for saving and loading XML.

```
    XDocument xDoc;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("root", new XElement("data")));
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = textBox1.Text;

        xDoc.Root.SetElementValue("data", input);

        rtxtXPreview.Text = xDoc.ToString();
        txtValuePreview.Text = xDoc.Root.Element("data").Value;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveAndLoad();
    }

    private void SaveAndLoad()
    {
        string dataNodeValue;
        xDoc.Save(path);
        dataNodeValue = xDoc.Descendants("data").First().Value;
        txtValuePreview.Text = dataNodeValue;
        rtxtXPreview.Text = xDoc.ToString();
    }
```

**textBox1:** is the input for the data element.

**rtxtXPreview:** is a rich textbox for displaying the text of the XML.

**txtValuePreview:** is a textbox for displaying the element  value.

The problem is that when I enter value like:

A

B

C

The XML shows fine with the line breaks but once I hit the button the document is saved without those. So when I debugged my code I found that the characters \n\r is replaced with \n so I searched for this problem and found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684032/linq-to-xml-generates-r-n-between-tags):

```
    private void SaveAndLoadFixed()
    {
        string dataNodeValue;

        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings =
            new XmlWriterSettings { NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None, Indent = true };

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(path, xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
        }

        //xDoc.Save(path);

        XElement xDatabaseElement;
        using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(path) { WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant })
        {
            xmlTextReader.MoveToContent();
            xDatabaseElement = XElement.Load(xmlTextReader);
        }

        dataNodeValue = xDatabaseElement.Descendants("data").First().Value;
        txtValuePreview.Text = dataNodeValue;
        rtxtXPreview.Text = xDatabaseElement.ToString();
    }
```

This worked fine but why the characters `\n\r` not replaced with `&#x13&#x10;` because when I tried to type the character `<` or `>` it was replaced with `&lt;` & `&gt;` respectively ?

Comment: Are you sure you mean \n\r (line feed followed by carriage return) and not \r\n (carriage return followed by line feed; as it normally is)?

Comment: for debugging purpose, can you try raw string/load from file instead of from textbox?

Comment: @Llama Yes, just an ordering mistake.

Comment: You might try to use ` NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize` to preserve newlines

Comment: You can use `XmlWriter` with settings `NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize`, though this will entitize only `\r` and not `\n` characters. To prevent removing `\r` chars on reading set `Normalization = false` on the `XmlTextReader`. This works also when writing was not used with entitized new line handling.